# getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN cerberus.profound.works

Tags: networking, docker-compose

2024-03-17T08:20:03.773651612Z FetchError: request to https://cerberus.profound.works/api/errors/cqrkw6a7416l2oh/production failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN cerberus.profound.works
2024-03-17T08:20:03.977787009Z     at ClientRequest. (/home/node/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/node-fetch/index.js:1:65756)
2024-03-17T08:20:03.977816808Z     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
2024-03-17T08:20:03.977821608Z     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:494:9)
2024-03-17T08:20:03.977825408Z     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
2024-03-17T08:20:03.977829208Z     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
2024-03-17T08:20:03.977896506Z     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
2024-03-17T08:20:03.977929506Z     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
2024-03-17T08:20:03.977933606Z   type: 'system',
2024-03-17T08:20:03.977937106Z   errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
2024-03-17T08:20:03.977951705Z   code: 'EAI_AGAIN'

I am getting this inside my web container logs? Can anyone help me understand what exactly the the issue is Because evreything is Fine from DNS prespective. Aove is a three tier architecture With pocket base, cerberus webapp & caddy server.